# Pod not visible to search.cpan or metacpan, why?

Tags: perl, document, cpan, perl-pod

I noticed that my pod links in my [WITH section](https://metacpan.org/module/XENO/Business-CyberSource-0.006001/lib/Business/CyberSource/Request/Authorization.pm) do not work. I looked to see the link was just [typoed](https://metacpan.org/module/XENO/Business-CyberSource-0.006001/lib/Business/CyberSource/Request/Role/BillingInfo.pm) but clicking the [source](https://metacpan.org/source/XENO/Business-CyberSource-0.006001/lib/Business/CyberSource/Request/Role/BillingInfo.pm) show's it's not, and that the Pod is there. Why does my pod not work on metacpan.org or search.cpan.org (it appears to with perldoc)?

*update: problem refuses to show itself after fixing*

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the links; it seems the POD on the destination module pages is not rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think this is it: you have the following in your `META.yml`.

```
no_index:
  file:
    - perlcritic.rc
  namespace:
    - Business::CyberSource::Request::Role
    - Business::CyberSource::Response::Role
    - Business::CyberSource::Role
```

This tells the CPAN not to index your POD. MetaCPAN and search.cpan hide them from the list as well.